# Context aware menu

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

Are there any patterns for implementing context aware menu's/buttons? Say I have a menu item called copy, and a multitude of datagrids on various tabs. I would like the copy menubutton to copy whatever is currently selected, which could be any of several different controls.

We've implemented a message broker throughout the app so its easy for various components to be notified when a button is pressed. So my first thought was for the button to notify onclick, then have each component check if its the currently selected item, and viola.

My first shot at this looked like the following:

```
bool isselected = false;
FocusManager.AddGotFocusHandler(mycontrol, (o, e) => { isselected = true; });
FocusManager.AddLostFocusHandler(mycontrol, (o, e) => { isselected = false; });

MessageBroker.Subscribe<CopyButtonClicked>(() =>
{
    if(isselected)
        // Do Copy
});
```

The problem is, of course, when you click the copy button, the previous control loses focus.

Am I approaching this problem wrong? What other ways are there to implement this kind of functionality.

Before someone remarks about the obvious, I realize this is bad UI design. Unfortunately I don't have any say about whether this gets implemented.

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use [`ApplicationCommands.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) or the like. BTW yes if you mash together UI and application logic everything will probably suck all the time.

Comment: @HighCore The view and viewmodels are much more segregated in our app, the example was to briefly illustrate the problem. Unfortunatley, copy is not the only thing we need to support. We have other options like Move Up where if a data grid is selected, then the row should move up. But if a treeview is selected, the node moves up. etc.

Comment: every word you say sounds to me like a ViewModel concern and never a View concern. have an `public ViewModel ActiveViewModel` property somewhere and implement `ICopyable` in your ViewModel or the like

Comment: @HighCore I dont understand how this solves the problem. The problem is how to make a single button context aware, so that it triggers functionality in the appropriate viewmodel depending on which control is selected.